Wire Antenna - Electrical Work
Life has gotten in the way of my ham radio hobby over the last 5+ years and I have forgotten a lot of my knowledge. I hope to have time to get back into it in the future.
My equipment setup:

Yaesu FT 891
Z100-plus auto tuner
'wire antenna' (this is where I forget the most) - see picture - left side connects to wire, right side just connected to fence by a rope. coaxial directly to the house.

I am located in an inner suburb where a large antenna is not practical. I ran a wire antenna from a tree to my fence and ran coaxial from the antenna to my house. The connection through the wall is just a barrel coaxial connector to make it through the wall. This all seemed to work well though I had read about better grounding potentially helping and the potential for lightning.
The area of my ham radio setup is on the other side of the house from the electrical service entry.
I am getting a service line upgrade and thinking of any other electrical work I need at the same time. Does my setup seem reasonable? Anything I could put on the list for the electrician without doing a lot of research that would improve my setup (not much time to do research).


First, welcome back! Yes, your setup seems reasonable. Fire it up and have some fun. 2 things come to mind for your question:
Circuit Breakers: do some test TX ASAP
There is still a large installed base of circuit breakers that trip in the presence of some HF/VHF transmissions. Do some test transmits at whatever your max power is on several of the HF bands to see if any of your breakers pop. If so, you'll want to mark which ones pop with a sticker and have them replaced with newer ones that have in-built RFI suppression.
And you'll want to let him know, before he shows up, how many you want to replace and at what ampacities so that he can come prepared without making a supply run.
Re lightning
There are several lighting arrestors available for purchase from DX Eng et al in several configurations. In your shoes, I'd look at the ones that have a female UHF coax connector on both sides.

The name "UHF" is a source of confusion, since the name of the connectors did not change when the frequency ranges were renamed. The design was named during an era when "UHF" meant frequencies over 30 MHz.

